# How many different types of sandwiches can a customer order?

Tags: combinatorics

I’m studying for the GED exam so I’ve been learning math combinations and permutations, which is one of the many subjects that will be on the exam. I’ve been doing a few practice questions and I wanted to know if my answer was correct for this word problem:

A deli offers a made-to-order sandwich to its customers. Customers can choose one type of bread, one type of meat, one type of cheese, and one type of lettuce. If the deli has four types of bread, five types of meat, eight types of cheeses, and three types of lettuce, how many different types of sandwiches can a customer order?
My answer was: 480. I multiplied 4 x 5 x 8 x 3. Is this the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: You answer is correct

Comment: Please use informative answers, that tell the users what your question is about. Second: just asking if your answer is correct is not the right use of this site; instead, if you really want help here, then you should also say **how** you arrived at your answer. After all, if you tell us that you believe that $16/64$ equals $1/4$ and ask if you are correct, you would be told “yes”, but if the reason you think it is correct is because you cancelled the sixes, then that’s a problem...

Comment: I've changed the tag to combinatorics.

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much! I wanted to make sure I understood what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just multiply the number of possibilities for each category, since the categories are all independent and there's no other stipulation.Your answer is correct.

$(4)(5)(8)(3)=480$

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much. I solved it the exact same way.

Comment: Please accept an answer that has helped you - this allows the thread to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct. To find the total amount of combinations, you multiply the number of possibilities in each section. Here, $4 \times 5\times8\times3=480$ combinations.